# Unknown impact of using ng-include with JQuery initialization

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am in the process of taking a website that is heavy in JQuery and converting it to a more angular-friendly design.  Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D0SR43WII1dRyjUpBMmy?p=preview), that represents the original website.  If you run this and click on the "Layouts" menu item, notice the submenu items collapse and expand.

If i create a template html file from the menu and use nginclude, suddenly the expand and collapse does not work.  Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yIeLagV5gQsPxGZSODmD?p=preview)

Can someone explain why?

```
<div data-ng-include="" src="'menuFull.tpl.html'" onload="OnTemplateLoaded()" data-ng-controller="MenuCtrl"></div>
```

All i can think of is App.Init is called before the nginclude is embedded in the page and therefore, some of the jQuery.on does not get hooked up?  Anyone see any ways of using nginclude but still getting it to expand/collapse?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question but `src="'menuFull.tpl.html'"` seems weird. Can you try `src="menuFull.tpl.html"` without single coutes?

Comment: Meh, that'll break it even more i guess. Sorry.

Comment: Are you aware that you don't have `.accordion` class on your template?

Comment: Neither does the version with the embedded elements though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Whats going wrong

Whats happening here is that the markup inside you include is not being updated by your App.init(). In your first example all the markup is present when you call init. All the work that needs to be done to "activate" your menus and bind the correct events to them works correctly.

In your second example the controller has updated the markup with the include template and run the controller to fill in the bindings. This is inserted into the page after you have called init at the bottom of the page. So the event bindings to make the menu show up are not present.

#### The fix

If you call App.init() inside your OnTemplateLoaded() function in the controller then you will see that the menu now works.

#### Some things to note:

First **EVERY** time your controller data syncs it replaces the template and you will have to rebind the events to the markup in your include.

Second is that App.init() targets the entire page. When rebinding or binding for a specific template or feature in your template you should use a selector that will target just that.

Lastly, if the data that your using in your controller is not going to be updated after its rendered, eg your just pulling the menu contents from the server and they don't change. You can fine tune your document load actions to work around this. So, choose to register the documents events though only Angular or jQuery, then define the order of execution. In that call bind your angular module to the page and afterward call App.init();